# How to extract data from an object API response Apps script goole sheets

Tags: javascript, api, google-sheets, response

//I want to achieve `"highestBid": "94628.41"` displayed in `A3` cell - the value of `highestBid` varies with time.

```js
function response() {
  var url = "https://api.zonda.exchange/rest/trading/ticker/BTC-PLN";
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://api.zonda.exchange/rest/trading/ticker/BTC-PLN");
  var obj = { highestBid: "94628.41" };
  type: "Fixed Multiple";
  Status: "Active";
  var result = Object.keys(obj).map((key) => [key, obj[key]]);
  Logger.log(result);
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("A3").setValue(result);
}
```

Comment: function response() {
var url = 'https://api.zonda.exchange/rest/trading/ticker/BTC-PLN'
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://api.zonda.exchange/rest/trading/ticker/BTC-PLN');
Logger.log(response);
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('A1').setValue(response);
}

Comment: My first code looks like this and the whole list displays correctly - but I want to extract data

Answer (score 0):

The most important thing for you to do is to get the response body as a `string` using [`getContentText()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/http-response#getContentText(String)) and parse it as JSON using [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) so you can access the values easily in JavaScript following the structure of the returned data:

```json
{
  "status": "Ok",
  "ticker": {
    "market": {
      "code": "BTC-PLN",
      "first": { "currency": "BTC", "minOffer": "0.0000468", "scale": 8 },
      "second": { "currency": "PLN", "minOffer": "5", "scale": 2 },
      "amountPrecision": 8,
      "pricePrecision": 2,
      "ratePrecision": 2
    },
    "time": "1663191022379",
    "highestBid": "94563.2",
    "lowestAsk": "94846.78",
    "rate": "94846.78",
    "previousRate": "94566.21"
  }
}
```

You should also make some other changes:

- use `const` instead of `var` to treat values as immutable and you might also be interested in their [scope](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp)
- you should check for the response code using [`getResponseCode()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/http-response#getResponseCode()) as if the request fails (which it can for many reasons) you won't be able to access the data or get unexpected data returned. See [HTTP status codes - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Response_status_codes).

For more details on what parsing means and how JSON and JavaScript are connected see [this explanation](https://www.programiz.com/javascript/json).
Here now how you can set the value of `highestBid` in cell `A3`.

```js
function response() {
  const url = "https://api.zonda.exchange/rest/trading/ticker/BTC-PLN";
  const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  if(response.getResponseCode != 200){
    Logger.log(`The request failed with status code ${response.getResponseCode()}`) 
  } else {
    // get the content of the response body as string (in UTF-8 encoding) 
    const responseStr = response.getContentText("UTF-8")
    // the string is in JSON format so we can now parse it to make it accessible in javascript 
    const data = JSON.parse(responseStr);
    // the hightest bid can now easily be obtained
    const highestBid = data.ticker.highestBid;
    Logger.log(`The highest bid is ${highestBid} until ${new Date(data.ticker.time).toLocaleString()}`)
    // set value in cell A3
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("A3").setValue(highestBid);
  }
}
```

By the way: `Object.entries(result)` returns the same result as `var result = Object.keys(obj).map((key) => [key, obj[key]]);`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your substantive answer - I just didn't know how to insert a JSON object into the API response. I will get acquainted with it.

Comment: I will write comments if I have any questions.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your help, you are doing a lot of good work - the script has started to work and returns the selected value to the spreadsheet.

Comment: **function response() {
  //getContentText() formula
  const url = "https://api.zonda.exchange/rest/trading/ticker/BTC-PLN";
  const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://api.zonda.exchange/rest/trading/ticker/BTC-PLN");
Logger.log(response.getContentText());
//JSON.parse() formula
const json = response.getContentText();
const data = JSON.parse(response);
const highestBid = data.ticker.highestBid;
Logger.log(`The highest bid is ${highestBid} until ${new Date(data.ticker.time).toLocaleString()}`)
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("A3").setValue(highestBid);
}
**

Comment: Your links and tips are extremely helpful. Now I want to combine several responses and break them into cells.